# ¿Cómo convertir un factor "negativo" a un número?

Tags: r, data

Tengo un `dataframe` con una columna compuesta por números negativos del tipo:

```
df1 <- (longitud = c("-2,9848165", "-2,9754304", "-2,5534295", "-2,6503331", "-2,6312"), latitud = c("42,6610", "43,0355365", "43,0224604", "43,0509888", "43,0491569", "43,0478618"))

> df1 

Longitud        Latitud
-2,9848165  43,0355365
-2,9754304  43,0224604
-2,5534295  43,0509888
-2,6503331  43,0491569
-2,6312     43,0478618
```

Cuando hago un str(df1), veo que Longitud y latitud son Factores. El caso es que tengo que convertirlos a numérico porque luego debo operar sobre dichas variables, y he creado una función que también tiene que considerar y operar sobre dichos valores.

He intentado con

```
df1$longitud<-as.numeric(df1$longitud) y me convierte los valores a 

> df1 

Longitud     Latitud
174            73
173            64
106            84
128            83
121            81
```

También he intentado importar los datos y poner `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` y veo que los importa como caracteres. Luego he tratado de poner nuevamente `as.numeric`, como lo mencioné anteriormente, y nuevamente me cambia los valores de las variables. ¿Alguna idea de qué debería hacer?

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema, no es que el dato sea un `factor`, sino el por que es un `factor`. Si te fijas en tu ejemplo, los "números" tienen la `,` como separador decimal, lo cual es señal que no han podido interpretarse como números. (El separador decimal normal es el `.`). Al no interpretarse como números, obviamente se trabajan como caracter. El resultado final es que no vas a poder convertirlos a numéricos por que no pueden interpretarse como tales.

Este evidentemente es un problema de importación del `data.frame`, o de la forma en que se salvan originalmente. No sabemos de dónde viene la información por lo que no podría asegurar una solución, pero si fuera un archivo `csv` podrías hacer algo así:

```
df1 <- read.csv2(file="archivo.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",")
```

En este caso, el separador de cada columna es el punto y coma `sep=";"` y definimos que el separador decimal es la coma no el punto con `dec=","`.

Aún así, es útil recordar, como convertir los factores numéricos a números reales. Al crear un `factor`, el valor de `labels` se define como un vector de caracteres numéricos, por ejemplo:

```
longitud = factor(c(-2.9848165, -2.9754304, -2.5534295, -2.6503331, -2.6312))
labels(longitud)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
levels(longitud)
[1] "-2.9848165" "-2.9754304" "-2.6503331" "-2.6312"    "-2.5534295"
```

Entonces al hacer `as.numeric(longitud)` simplemente estamos convirtiendo el vector de `labels`, es decir `"1" "2" "3" "4" "5"`.

La ayuda de `factor` te da una idea de lo que se debería hacer

> To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
>   as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
>   than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

```
as.numeric(as.character(longitud))
[1] -2.984816 -2.975430 -2.553430 -2.650333 -2.631200
```

o bien:

```
as.numeric(levels(longitud))[longitud]
[1] -2.984816 -2.975430 -2.553430 -2.650333 -2.631200
```

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente.